Collapsing directed weighted graph in python using igraph
I have a directed weighted graph that represents corporate ownership. I am trying to collapse subgraph that have ultimate shareholders to:

Vertically remove intermediate unlisted entities with the new edge taking the weight of the weakest of the two edges (but don't delete the ultimate shareholder U even if unlisted),
Aggregate ownership for each connected pairs of remaining nodes, and
Retain only ownership edges that are 30% or more in aggregate.

I am using igraph and python (in a PyCharm IDE if that matters).
I have created a toy graph and have gotten somewhat close. Here is the toy graph:
gt = ig.Graph(directed=True)
  
#´Add vertices (U, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) 
gt.add_vertices(["U", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]) 
 
#Add edges with weights 
edges = [("U", "A"), ("A", "B"), ("A", "C"), ("A", "F"), ("A", "H"),
          ("B", "D"), ("B", "E"), ("C", "E"), ("C", "F"), ("H", "G")]  

weights = [0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.1, 0.6, 0.4, 0.45, 0.25, 0.2, 0.1]  # Corresponding weights

gt.add_edges(edges) 
gt.es['weight'] = weights  

#Add the 'listco' attribute for each vertex (A, D, E, F, G are listed) 
listco = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0] 
gt.vs['listco'] = listco


This toy graph looks like this:

Here is what I want the collapsed graph to look like:

I have code to do this that partially works, but it is still retaining G and doesn't have D.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Function to iteratively remove non-listco nodes and collapse the graph
def iteratively_remove_non_listco_nodes(graph, root_name="U"):
    while True:
        removed_any = False
        non_listco_nodes = [v.index for v in graph.vs if v['listco'] == 0 and v['name'] != root_name]

        for node in non_listco_nodes:
            if node >= len(graph.vs):  # Check if node is still valid
                continue

            predecessors = graph.predecessors(node)
            successors = graph.successors(node)

            #Collapse edges from predecessors to successors
            for pred in predecessors:
                for succ in successors:
                    if graph.are_adjacent(pred, succ):
                        eid = graph.get_eid(pred, succ)
                        new_weight = min(graph.es[graph.get_eid(pred, node)]['weight'],
                                         graph.es[graph.get_eid(node, succ)]['weight'])
                        graph.es[eid]['weight'] += new_weight
                    else:
                        new_weight = min(graph.es[graph.get_eid(pred, node)]['weight'],
                                         graph.es[graph.get_eid(node, succ)]['weight'])
                        graph.add_edge(pred, succ, weight=new_weight)

            #Remove the node and its associated edges
            graph.delete_vertices(node)
            removed_any = True

        if not removed_any:  # If no nodes were removed in this iteration, we're done
            break

#Copy the graph to avoid altering the original
collapsed_gt = gt.copy()

#Iteratively remove non-listco nodes, preserving the root node "U"
iteratively_remove_non_listco_nodes(collapsed_gt, root_name="U")

#Plotting the collapsed graph using a tree layout
layout = collapsed_gt.layout_reingold_tilford(root=[collapsed_gt.vs.find(name="U").index])
positions = {i: layout[i] for i in range(len(collapsed_gt.vs))}

#Invert the y-coordinates to place the root at the top
for i in positions:
    positions[i][1] = -positions[i][1]

weights = collapsed_gt.es['weight']

plt.close('all')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

#Draw nodes for the graph
for vertex_id, position in positions.items():
    ax.scatter(*position, s=100)
    ax.text(*position, collapsed_gt.vs[vertex_id]["name"], fontsize=10, ha='center', va='center')

#Draw edges with weight labels
for edge_id, edge in enumerate(collapsed_gt.es):
    src, dst = edge.tuple
    src_pos = positions[src]
    dst_pos = positions[dst]

#Draw the edge with uniform thickness
    ax.plot([src_pos[0], dst_pos[0]], [src_pos[1], dst_pos[1]], 'k-', lw=2)  # Uniform thickness

    #Calculate midpoint of the edge for the label
    mid_pos = [(src_pos[0] + dst_pos[0]) / 2, (src_pos[1] + dst_pos[1]) / 2]

    #Offset the label slightly from the edge
    offset = 0.05 * (dst_pos[1] - src_pos[1])
    ax.text(mid_pos[0], mid_pos[1] + offset, f"{weights[edge_id]:.2f}", fontsize=10, ha='center', va='center',
            color='red')

plt.show()

#Explicitly print the edges in a readable format
print("Collapsed graph edges:")
for edge in collapsed_gt.es:
    print(
        f"{collapsed_gt.vs[edge.source]['name']} -> {collapsed_gt.vs[edge.target]['name']} (weight: {edge['weight']})")


print(collapsed_gt)

Here is the result from this code:

I would really appreciate help figuring out where I am going wrong.
